# IP packet has trailer on the receiver side , but not on the sender side

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, wireshark

I have a simple c++ code that build SYN packet and send it by raw socket.
I allocate 54 bytes for this (Ethernet 14 bytes ).

Wireshark on the sender show 54 bytes, but on the receiver wiresark show 60 bytes . 6 bytes are added as a trailer to the end of the packet.

The same happen if i send the packet with scapy. (54 on sender, 60 on receiver)

Can you please advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ethernet can't send frames that are shorter than 64 bytes, where 60 bytes is payload and 4 bytes is a checksum (the FCS). The FCS gets stripped out by the hardware and is never seen by software. That's why the application will only see 60 bytes.

So the extra bytes you see added get added on by the hardware and there's nothing you can do about it. The trailer should be all zeros though.

Wireshark has good information about this on their wiki: http://wiki.wireshark.org/Ethernet

Comment: But i am getting 60 bytes and not 64

Comment: Correct, the 4 byte FCS is stripped by the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

As @Gille mentioned, the additional data is padding because of Ethernet limitations. But IP has a 'length' field that will tell you how much of the packet is real payload and how much is padding. Your code (and any proper code out there) must be able to handle padding and that's what the 'length' field ist for.

Assuming, you're using IPv4, have a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Packet_structure . I'm talking about the "Total Length" field.